# Adding multi pane layouts to a single layout app

Tags: android, layout

I have a app near completion and want to add multi pane views to accommodate tablets.
First is this possible when the layouts are already coded and if it is possible are there any good tutorials out there.

Thanks 
Ciaran

Answer (score 0):

Did this using Fragmentation, but probably better doing this from the beginning of project.